# Запись в файл питон

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть две переменные a и b. Как записать их в файл чтобы они начинались каждый с новой строки в файле?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    result.write(str(a) + '\n')
    result.write(str(b) + '\n')
```

?

Comment: `print(a, b, end="\n", file=file)` ?

Answer (score 3):

Работает для Python 3.6 и выше

```
def writer(row):
    with open('file.txt', 'a') as file: #  'a' - Open file in append mode. If file does not exist, it creates a new file.
        file.writelines(f'{row}\n')

writer(a)
writer(b)
```

Comment: Очень вычурный способ:)

Comment: @Victor Чем вычурный?

Comment: Почему нельзя просто `file.write(f"{row}\n")`